# convert coordinates into binary image python

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a GUI in which I can load an image from disk and convert the mouse motion ( drawing the contours ) into coordinates. Now I need to convert the coordinates into a binary image and I don't know how. 
Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import numpy as np
import cv2

class Browse_image :
 def __init__ (self,master) :

  frame = Frame(master)
  frame.grid(sticky=W+E+N+S)
  self.browse = Button(frame, text="Browse", command = lambda: browseim(self))
  self.browse.grid(row=13, columnspan=1)
  self.photo = PhotoImage(file="browse.png")
  self.label = Label(frame, image=self.photo)
  self.label.grid(row=1,rowspan=10)
  self.label.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.mouseevent)
 def mouseevent(self,event):
   w=self.photo.width()
   h=self.photo.height()
   a = np.zeros(shape=(h,w))
   #print event.x, event.y
   a[event.x,event.y]=1
```

plt.imsave('binary.png', a, cmap=cm.gray)

```
def browseim(self):
  path = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("png files","*.png"),("jpeg files",
   "*.jpeg")) )
  if path:
    img = Image.open(path)
    self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)                    
    self.label.configure(image = self.photo)
   #self.label.image = self.photo


root= Tk()
b= Browse_image(root)
root.mainloop()
```

`

Comment: how is the behavior of this program different than what you expect? It looks like you're tracking mouse movements via the bind. Why is that not working for you? What does "Convert the coordinates into a binary image" mean?

Comment: I need to convert the coordinates into a binary matrix as a binary image (1 0 1 1 0 0 0) so for each point given it puts a 1 in the matrix, 0 for the rest.

Comment: why to you need it ? what will you do later with this coordinates ? if nothing then keep it in 2-dimensional numpy array: `matrix = np.zeros((height,width))` and later `matrix[y][x] = 1`

Comment: I updated my code, I get the binary image but with the first point only, any idea about the loop I have to use to make the matrix take all the coordinates while the mouse is moving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are creating a new empty array at each mouse event with the line `a = np.zeros(shape=(h,w))` in mouseevent. To fix that you should have `a` declared in the `__init__` as an attribute (ie `self.a = np.zeros(shape=(h,w))`) so that you can acces and update it without overwriting it in your `mouseevent` function.